# Al poner la letra correcta, el programa sigue entrando al bucle de la incorrecta

Tags: java

Si la letra es incorrecta, el programa debe imprimir "PENJAT", que ya lo hace.
Si la letra es correcta, el programa tiene que sustituir las letras de la palabra secreta, sin entrar al siguiente bucle del "PENJAT"

Este es el código:

```
case 3:
                System.out.println("Introduzca una letra: ");
            letra = lector.next().charAt(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < palabra_secreta.length; i++) {
                if (letra == palabra_secreta[i]) {
                    palabra[i] = palabra_secreta[i];
                    encontrada = true;
                } else {
                    encontrada = false;
                }

                if (!encontrada) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < penalizacion.length; j++) {
                        muerte[j] = penalizacion[j];
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Por favor, inserta tu código en formato de texto, no en imagen.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Evita poner imágenes con código, es mejor copiar/pegar el texto mismo del código. Las imágenes son difíciles de ver en dispositivos pequeños y no se puede copiar si se quiere reproducir el problema. En cuanto al error, ten en cuenta que en Java, para comparar cadenas tienes que usar `equals()`, no el comparador `==`. Si lo pones así debería funcionar: **`if ( letra.equals(palabra_secreta[i]) ) { //... }`**

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias por su respuesta, @A.Cedano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas ejecutando el segundo bucle para cada letra de la palabra secreta, lo que debes hacer es ejecutarlo una vez completada la busqueda de caracteres en la palabra secreta, de esta manera:

```
encontrada = false;
for (int i = 0; i < palabra_secreta.length; i++) {
    if (letra == palabra_secreta[i]) {
        palabra[i] = palabra_secreta[i];
        encontrada = true;
    }
}

if (!encontrada) {
    for (int j = 0; j < penalizacion.length; j++) {
        muerte[j] = penalizacion[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta correcta @Jeroni Chamorro

Answer (score 0):

Para sustituir caracteres o secuencias de caracteres en Strings puedes usar el método replace:

```
String saludo = "Hola como estas";
saludo = saludo.replace('o', '@');
// saludo ahora almacena la cadena "H@la c@m@ estas"
```

Además, para acceder a la letra de una posición de un String se usa el método charAt:

```
System.out.println(saludo.charAt(0);
```

Tu código podría quedar así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < palabra_secreta.length; i++) {
    encontrada = false;
    if (letra == palabra_secreta[i]) {
        palabra.replace(palabra.charAt(i), palabra_secreta.charAt(i));
        encontrada = true;
    }

    if (!encontrada) {
        for (int j = 0; j < penalizacion.length; j++) {
            muerte[j] = penalizacion[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El código se podría mejorar pero así te serviría.